# innerHTML doesn't refresh the display on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Beginner Javascript question.

When I set the innerHTML field of an element - it doesn't referesh the display, until I scroll up and down in the page. This only happens in IE9

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="zzz">
<li>
    <input title="Delete" name="DeleteFiles" value="a5e342fd-9180-416b-9938-e66218f275ee"
        id="DeleteCb" onchange="SetDelete(DeleteCb,DeleteLabel)" type="checkbox">  <span id="DeleteLabel" > </span>
    <a href="MyJavaTest_files/_MG_0126.jpg">_MG_0126.jpg</a>
    <br>
    <img style="max-width: 400px;" src="MyJavaTest_files/_MG_0126.jpg">
</li> </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
SetDelete = function (checkBox, Label) {
    if (checkBox.checked)
        Label.innerHTML="<B>Delete<B>";
    else
        Label.innerHTML = "";}</script>
```

Here is how it looks when I click:

[image]

And here it how it looks after I minimize and maximize, or anything else that will cause it to repaint that area.

I also tried jQuery HTML and got the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.getElementById` since you are passing `id` value not node itself:

```
SetDelete = function (checkBox, Label) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkBox);
    var Label = document.getElementById(Label);
    if (checkBox.checked)
        Label.innerHTML="<B>Delete<B>";
    else
        Label.innerHTML = "";
}
```

And use quotes while calling:

```
onchange="SetDelete('DeleteCb', 'DeleteLabel')"
```

---

Also avoid using variable names such as `Checkbox`, `Label`, `Submit`, `Button`, etc since they would create problems which becomes hard to find.

Comment: My intention was not to send the ID value, rather the element itself.
I don't want to use Id's here, as this like will exist multiple time in the page, thus many elements will have the same id.